# Use keyframes to animate in React

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

The idea is to have a circle that spins round and round but the spinning doesn't work. It's only a static circle.

Is there a way to use keyframes in react, besides styled-components because I get a 'can't resolve styled components' error when I try that? I have installed styled-components.

My component

```
import React from 'react'

const Body = () => (
  <section className='Container'>
    <section className='Center'>
      <section className='Circle'></section>
    </section>
  </section>
)

export default Body
```

css

```
.Circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #f1c40f #e74c3c #9b59b6 #2ecc71;
  animation: animateCircle 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animateCircle {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: (360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: your 100% keyframe is missing the `rotate` keyword.

Comment: Damn! Thank you.